# Using Codeigniter in a Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

This might seem a bit of a weird question but I have some CI code I'd like to include as a WP-plugin.

When doing this, how would you access a controller function as a shortcode, for example:

myurl.com/controller1/method1

would map to controller.php

```
function method1(){
}
```

Assuming the CI is in the content/plugins folder as an installed plugin, how would I map myurl.com/controller1/method1 to a WP shortcode such as **[controller1-method1]**

Or would it be simpler to re-write as a wordpress plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hi try wordpressigniter to create plugins with codeigntier

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-igniter/

Comment: hi thanks I think this is a useful plugin for connecting WP and CI but I don't think it handles shortcodes? does it?